# Python HTML template ternary operator

Tags: python, html, django, if-statement, ternary-operator

I've come across with different python ternary operators such as:

```
a if b else 0
```

but it didn't work when I tried to include it inside Django HTML template

```
{% a if b else 0 %}
```

Here is the exact code that I'll be using but won't work:

```
{% 'error' if form.title.errors else '' %}
```

or

```
{% form.title.errors ? 'error' : '' %}
```

I don't like to do the usual

```
{% if form.title.errors %}error{% endif %}
```

because it looks bulky in my opinion especially if I add an else statement.

Any suggestions? or should I just stick with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get more or less the behavior you want by using the `yesno` filter ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno)):

```
{{ form.title.errors|yesno:"errors," }}
```

Comment: superb!, tried this but didn't know that you need to insert a comma at the end

Answer (score 2):

In Django, the templatetags just support `{% if %}{% else %}{% endif %}`. If you don't want to use:

```
{% if form.title.errors %}error{% endif %}
```

You can try:

```
{{ error|default:'' }}
```

And the test in django template is bellow:

```
...from django.template import Context, Template
...from django.conf import settings
...settings.configure()
...t = Template("My name is: {{ name|default:'anonymous' }} ")
```

If default:

```
...t.render(Context({}))
```

it will return:

```
'My name is anonymous '
```

If has name:

```
...t.render(Context({"name": "John"}))
```

result:

```
'My name is John '
```

Read more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/